# GAE and Python: My dictionary values return None instead of an object

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using Python and GAE, and I'm trying to create a dictionary with keys being the userid and values being a 'Student' object. However, my dictionary's values are None rather than a student object.

```
{'60': , '59': }
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction!

Student.py

```
class Student:

def __init__(self, name, s_id, rew = {}):
    self.name = name.strip()
    self.rewards = {"Creativity": 0, "Helping Others":0, "Participation":0, "Insight":0}
    self.totalRewardPoints = 0   
    self.s_id = s_id
```

Main.py (I've only included the relevant code)

```
class PageHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def write(self, *a, **kw):
    self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

def initialize(self, *a, **kw):
    webapp2.RequestHandler.initialize(self, *a, **kw)

def create_students(self):
    user = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE position='student'")

    for u in user:

        temp_id = str(u.key().id())
        self.students[temp_id] = student.Student(u.name, temp_id)

class MainPage(PageHandler):

students = {}

def get(self):

    user = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE position='student'")

    for u in user:

        temp_id = str(u.key().id())
        self.students[temp_id] = student.Student(u.name, temp_id)

    self.write(self.students)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

Comment: Please reformat your code, the indenting is all wrong.

Comment: Apart from the issues Tim's already identified, there's a couple of major Python problems with your code. Never use a dictionary literal as a default function parameter as you do in `__init__` - every invocation will get the _same_ dictionary, and if you modify it, all subsequent invocations will of course get the modified version. Likewise, your definition of `students` in the `MainPage` class is a class-level variable, not an instance variable - define it inside `get()` instead.

Comment: Also, if `Student` is supposed to be a model class, you definitely shouldn't override `__init__`. It's difficult to do right - use a factory method instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you Student class needs to inherit from some model class implementing appengine datastore persistence.  If you you are using the original datastore api then db.Model, if ndb then nbd.Model.

Secondly you haven't shown how you write (put()) student entities to the datastore.  Based on the fact you are not inheriting from either (db or ndb) it's unlikely you are saving anything to the datastore.

Unless of course you are not including your actual code.  If you are using db.Model as the base class, then your rewards field is not going to work.  You should probably look at ndb as an alternate starting point and use a Structured Property.

You probably need to read up on the appengine storing data over view doc  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview#Python_Datastore_API  you code looks nothing like GAE (Google Appengine code)

You student class should look something like (if you want a rewards field to have some structure)

```
class Reward(ndb.Model):
    reward = ndb.StringProperty()
    value = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class Student(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    rewards = ndb.StructuredProperty(Reward, repeated=True)
    total_reward_points = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    s_id = ndb.StringProperty()
```

otherwise if you use db.Model then rewards would be a db.BlobProperty() and you would then pickle is use json to encode rewards dictionary using pickle.dumps or json.dumps when saving data.

Comment: I just found my mistake - I forgot iterating a dictionary via for...in... returns the keys not the values. 

I had assumed my mistake was due to the way I was setting up my classes but it was a much more basic one.

Comment: That is one mistake but see what I have written, the code you supplied could never work with appengine datastore and the db.GqlQuery etc...